# Can i combine bootstrapToggle with http.get?

Tags: android, jquery

I have want make some toggle in android and i used bootstrapToggle and i don't know how to combine with http.get. I try used toggle like this in my html

```js
$(function() {
  $('#toggle-two').bootstrapToggle({
    on: 'Lock',
    off: 'Unlock'
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="toggle-two" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-width="100">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bootstrap Toggle library exposes the usual `change` event of the underlying checkbox which you can hook to when the toggle is changed. Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#toggle-two').bootstrapToggle({
    on: 'Lock',
    off: 'Unlock'
  }).on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({ 
      url: '/yourpage.foo',
      data: { checked: $(this).prop('checked') },
      success: function() {
        console.log('It worked!');
      }
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: thank it work although you forget } after console. After all it work. Thanks again

Comment: Ah yes, I added an extra `)` by mistake. Glad you got it working :)

Comment: can i ask for question? your code if i change on but if i want change off it same code ?